# Receive Local Notification In watchkit

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, watchkit, apple-watch, ios-extensions

I have setup Local Notification as below :

```
-(void)startLocalNotification 
{

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hello! This is Local Notification!" forKey:@"Notification"];
    notification.userInfo = infoDict;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

I received notification on iPhone Simulator. But it will not fired notification of watchkit app. I am using below method in NotificationController.m in watchkit extension -

```
- (void)didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler
{
     NSLog(@"Notification Received ..");
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);

}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not receiving local notification in watchkit App.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

See Apple Watch Programming Guide [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

`When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch.`

So you don't need to worry about to send notification on Watch, iOS will do it for you.

Anyhow if you want to send notification on watch only you can use [Darwin Notification Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html), but keep in mind there are some limitations, you can check in the given link.

You can also use [shared container](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) for communication between App and extension.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Also remember that local notifications are not supported in the simulator at this time.

Comment: iPhone or iPad simulator support Local Notifications.

Comment: But not on WatchKit. It's mentioned in the docs and the forums.

Comment: To elaborate on this, if you want to trigger the watch to receive the local notification, I believe you can do it simply by having the iPhone be asleep when the notification arrives.

Comment: so we can only receive remote notifications in iWatch??